# divisibility K and sum of digits of the number K by N

Tags: nt.number-theory

For each number N there is a number K such that K is divisible by N and  sum of digits of the number K is divided by N?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. Let $m$ be some natural number with $10^m>N$. Then take $$K=N+10^mN+\ldots+10^{m(N-1)}N.$$ It is easy to see that $K$ is divisible by $N$. Decimal expansion of $K$ is basically the same as the decimal expansion of $N$, repeated $N$ times (with some zeroes added if $m$ is not minimal), thus if the sum of digits of $N$ equals $s$, then the sum of digits of $K$ equals $sN$ and this is divisible by $N$, as needed.

One can also use $K=10^M(10^{N\varphi(N)}-1)$ for $M$ large enough (i.e. $M\geq \max(\nu_2(N),\nu_5(N))$).

Comment: Also, it seems to be an interesting problem to estimate $K(N)$ --- the smallest such $K$ for $N$ large. The first example provides the proof of $\log K(N) \ll N\log N$ and it is completely trivial that $\log K(N) \gg N$. Is there any better lower bounds for special $N$?..